# ansible jinja2 same var for same file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I use one j2 template for multiple config.
I need take every item in services items in same config file name.
I should get one of the list values in the file of the same name and the next value from the list in the corresponding file name.
But it's not work right for me.
Part of my templates/service.j2

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ common.fullname }}-{% for item in services %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}"
```

ansible/task/main.yml

```
---
- name: copy manifest billing
  template:
    src: templates/service.j2
    dest: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    "{{ services }}"
```

ansible/vars/main.yml

```
services:
  - billing
  - cart
  - checkout
```

Now it take

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "hf-billingcartcheckout"
```

I'm expecting get 3 files with output:

billing

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "hf-billing"
```

cart

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: "hf-cart"
```

output

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: "hf-checkout"
```

I need to get my variable from list in another variable
Part of my templates/service.j2

```
values: "{{ "serviceEnvs.{{ item }}.values" }}"
```

Part of my vars/main.yml

```
     serviceEnvs:
      billing:
        values: 2
      cart:
        values: 2
      checkout:
        values: 2
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting exactly? Please do not reply in a comment, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

As the syntax clearly says:

> `name: "{{ common.fullname }}-{% for item in services %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}"`

is looping over all the items in the `services` list and emitting the name as a string, but according to your description, what you really want is

```
name: "{{ common.fullname }}-{{ item }}"
```

because the `item` variable is defined by the use of `with_items:` in your `template:` task

Comment: Thank you. I add one more question about env.